# Tricky wide to long conversion in Pandas with multi-index columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
stock  date         type1 type2 volume_A qtit_A volume_B qtit_B
'ABC' '2013-01-01'  1     2     1000     5      2500     6
'ABC' '2013-01-02'  1     3     4000     10     2500     0
```

and I would like to reshape it as follows:

```
stock  date         type1 type2 volume qtit type
'ABC' '2013-01-01'  1     2     1000     5   A    
'ABC' '2013-01-01'  1     2     2500     6   B   
'ABC' '2013-01-02'  1     3     4000     10  A 
'ABC' '2013-01-02'  1     3     2500     0   B
```

where you can see that the columns `['volume_A','qtit_A','volume_B','qtit_B']` are broken down in `['volume','qtit']` with a type indicator to remember which type of volume/price we are looking at.

I am struggling to have that done in Pandas in a clean way (using `melt` or `stack()` for instance)

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set `['date','stock','type1','type2']` as the `index`, then you can split the remaining column labels on `'_'`, create a MultiIndex from these tuples, and then move the `A`,`B` labels into the `index` using `stack`. `reset_index` then produces the desired result by moving the index levels back into columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02'],
 'qtit_A': [5, 10],
 'qtit_B': [6, 0],
 'stock': ['ABC', 'ABC'],
 'type1': [1, 1],
 'type2': [2, 3],
 'volume_A': [1000, 4000],
 'volume_B': [2500, 2500]})

df = df.set_index(['date','stock','type1','type2'])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([col.split('_', 1) for col in df.columns])
result = df.stack(level=1).reset_index()
result = result.rename(columns={'level_4':'type'})
print(result)
```

yields:

```
         date stock  type1  type2 type  qtit  volume
0  2013-01-01   ABC      1      2    A     5    1000
1  2013-01-01   ABC      1      2    B     6    2500
2  2013-01-02   ABC      1      3    A    10    4000
3  2013-01-02   ABC      1      3    B     0    2500
```

Answer (score 4):

```
pd.lreshape(df.assign(type_A=['A']*len(df), type_B=['B']*len(df)), 
            {'volume': ['volume_A', 'volume_B'], 
             'qtit': ['qtit_A', 'qtit_B'], 
             'type': ['type_A', 'type_B']})
Out: 
           date  stock  type1  type2  qtit type  volume
0  '2013-01-01'  'ABC'      1      2     5    A    1000
1  '2013-01-02'  'ABC'      1      3    10    A    4000
2  '2013-01-01'  'ABC'      1      2     6    B    2500
3  '2013-01-02'  'ABC'      1      3     0    B    2500
```

Assigning two new columns for type may not be necessary considering the output is ordered based on the order of the lists.

Comment: haha thats a great catch but can we safely assume the function is behaving correctly? experimental could mean no support = bug everywhere?

Comment: ok thanks can you just explain the assign part? I dont quite get what you are doing here

Comment: thanks buddy but this time I think `unutbu`'s proposal is the safest bet!